# Display theorem and axiom more compact

Tags: math-mode, newtheorem

I would like to make my axioms a little more compact by removing the empty spaces. It is possible to reduce the space I’ve filled with red lines on the following picture. I have in my work some axioms, and they take a full page, and it looks pretty empty. So I would like to compact the display.

By the way, I use the following code:

```
\lipsum[1]
\begin{axiom}{Axiom of Transitivity}
\[
    P(x, y) \land P(y, z) \rightarrow P(x, z)
\]
\end{axiom}
\lipsum[1]
```

[image: An axiom with a lot of empty space]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possibility with the `thmtools` package: I define a *compact* theorem style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\declaretheoremstyle[%
spaceabove=4pt, spacebelow=4pt,%
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,%
notefont=\mdseries\itshape, notebraces={\textup{(}}\textup{)},%
bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,%
postheadspace=0.5em]{compact}
%
\declaretheorem[style=compact, preheadhook={\abovedisplayskip=2pt\belowdisplayskip=0pt}]{axiom}%{Axiom}%

\begin{document}

\lipsum[10]
\begin{axiom}[Axiom of Transitivity]
\[
    P(x, y) \land P(y, z) \rightarrow P(x, z)
\]
\end{axiom}
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I add another possibility with `amsart` documentclass.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[theoremfont]{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{ax}{Axiom}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\setcounter{ax}{16}
\begin{ax}{Axiom of Transitivity}
\[
    P(x, y) \land P(y, z) \rightarrow P(x, z)
\]
\end{ax}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A generic setting for “compact equations”

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newenvironment{compactequation}
 {\compactequations\begin{equation}}
 {\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}
\newenvironment{compactequation*}
 {\compactequations\begin{equation*}}
 {\end{equation*}\ignorespacesafterend}
\newcommand{\compactequations}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt plus 1pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt plus 1pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{axiom}{16} % just to reproduce your picture

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{axiom}
Axiom of transitivity
\begin{compactequation*}
    P(x, y) \land P(y, z) \rightarrow P(x, z)
\end{compactequation*}
\end{axiom}

\lipsum[2][1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your axioms have all the same structure, that is, some text with a single formula and nothing else, you can do it in a different way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newtheorem{axiominner}{Axiom}
\newenvironment{axiom}
 {%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt plus 1pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt plus 1pt}%
  \axiominner
 }
 {\endaxiominner}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{axiominner}{16} % just to reproduce your picture

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{axiom}
Axiom of transitivity
\[
    P(x, y) \land P(y, z) \rightarrow P(x, z)
\]
\end{axiom}

\lipsum[2][1-5]

\end{document}
```

and the output is the same as above.